# Displaying decimal values as a result after looping in C

Tags: c

I am trying to complete a program that displays the decimal (acting as a percentage) in which a diamond, club, heart, or spade in a card deck will be drawn out of 1000 times. Here is the code that I have done:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned int freq1 = 0;
    unsigned int freq2 = 0;
     unsigned int freq3 = 0;
      unsigned int freq4 = 0;

        for (unsigned int draw = 1; draw <= 1000; ++draw) {
            int face = 1 +rand() % 4;

            switch (face) {

                case 1:
                ++freq1;
                break;

                case 2:
                ++freq2;
                break;

                case 3:
                ++freq3;
                break;

                case 4:
                ++freq4;
                break;
            }
        }

        printf("Percent of diamonds is %u\n", freq1);
        printf("Percent of clubs is %u\n", freq2);
        printf("Percent of hearts is %u\n", freq3);
        printf("Percent of spades is %u\n", freq4);

}
```

When I run the code it gets the correct drawn numerical values out of 1000. Here is the input:

```
Percent of diamonds is 249                                                                                                                                                
Percent of clubs is 252                                                                                                                                                   
Percent of hearts is 258                                                                                                                                                  
Percent of spades is 241
```

I am attempting to get the program to input a calculated decimal value from those numbers, such as this:

```
Percent of diamonds is 0.25
```

So far, I have tried to correct this by declaring the results as floats and having the frequency calculated in each draw divided by 1000 so that the result would be the decimal value that I am attempting to display. Here is my attempted code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned int freq1 = 0;
    unsigned int freq2 = 0;
     unsigned int freq3 = 0;
      unsigned int freq4 = 0;
      float res1, res2, res3, res4;

        for (unsigned int draw = 1; draw <= 1000; ++draw) {
            int face = 1 +rand() % 4;

            switch (face) {

                case 1:
                ++freq1;
                break;

                case 2:
                ++freq2;
                break;

                case 3:
                ++freq3;
                break;

                case 4:
                ++freq4;
                break;
            }
        }

    res1= freq1/1000;
    res2= freq2/1000;
    res3= freq3/1000;
    res4= freq4/1000;

        printf("Percent of diamonds is %.2f\n", res1);
        printf("Percent of clubs is %.2f\n", res2);
        printf("Percent of hearts is %.2f\n", res3);
        printf("Percent of spades is %.2f\n", res4);
}
```

However, when I tried to run it, I ended up with this result input:

```
Percent of diamonds is 0.00                                                                                                                                               
Percent of clubs is 0.00                                                                                                                                                  
Percent of hearts is 0.00                                                                                                                                                 
Percent of spades is 0.00
```

Apologies for the long post, but I would appreciate any help to figure this problem out as this is the only thing I need to solve in order to complete this program. Thank you!

Comment: Please learn how to *properly* indent your code.

Comment: Why are you indenting code in the same scope?

Comment: You should consider using an array of 4 (or even 5) entries, suitably zeroed, to record the numbers.  It will collapse your switch into a single statement, and you use a loop instead to print the results.  You'll need an appropriate array of suit names, of course.

Comment: I am not purposely trying to indent my code like that, I am just trying to seperate it from the text and it indented in such a fashion when I labelled it as a C question. Apologies if this is an inconvenience. Aprogrammer has solved my problem and the program is functioning. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that something like `res1= freq1/1000` is first computed as an integer as both arguments are integers and then converted to float.  Use instead something like `res1= freq1/1000.0` so that at least one argument is a floating point, the second will be converted to floating point automatically.